# Headers: double line after text

Tags: header-footer, rules, line

[image: How can I create a header exactly like this?]

How can I create a header exactly like this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Which document class you use? Use of the `fancyhdr` and `\rule` can be useful for your page design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the dimensions to your taste.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[L]{Bla Bla Bla \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{4pt}{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}}\makebox[0cm][l]{\rule{10cm}{2pt}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

[image]